# Difference between general linear model and generalized linear model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, definition

Is there a big difference between general linear model and generalized linear model?
I am quite confused a bit with the two.

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) or even [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_general_and_generalized_linear_models). A quick search on this site also reveals [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/general-linear-model-vs-generalized-linear-model-with-an-identity-link-functio). Given the last link, this question is possibly a duplicate.

Comment: There's a couple of related posts [How does the generalized linear model generalize the general linear model?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62691/how-does-the-generalized-linear-model-generalize-the-general-linear-model) and [General Linear Model vs. Generalized Linear Model (with an identity link function?)](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/general-linear-model-vs-generalized-linear-model-with-an-identity-link-functio); between them they might help, ... ctd

Comment: ctd... but neither quite seems to serve as an ideal introductory level explanation of the two side-by-side (the first takes general linear models as given, the second treats the second as a generalization of the first, which is broadly though not strictly correct but perhaps not the clearest way to deal with your question). Have a read of the links; if they don't cover what you need perhaps you can clarify your question a little to clearly identify what you most need explained. It might be worth having a question with this specific title on site.

Comment: @Glen_b according the the comments seems my understanding of general linear model is not correct.

Comment: @hxd1011 Glen's links are good. Your answer doesn't address the link function and response distribution. You only gave some R examples.

Comment: @StudentT thanks for your feedback I deleted my answer.